# Adding vscode like code editor to react application

Tags: reactjs, web, visual-studio-code, web-applications, code-editor

I want to embed a code editor in my react application. The code editor should be like vscode. Some website -(https://play.tailwindcss.com/, https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/) use these vscode type code editors in their webpages. My simple question is how can I embed them and are there any libraries available. I have seen something called ace but that isn't like vscode.

Thanks :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Later after looking html source I found that its - https://microsoft.github.io/monaco-editor/

Comment: , a link to a solution is welcome, but please ensure your answer is useful without it: [add context around the link](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/8259) so your fellow users will have some idea what it is and why it is there, then quote the most relevant part of the page you are linking to in case the target page is unavailable. [Answers that are little more than a link may be deleted.](/help/deleted-answers)

Answer (score 0):

There are a couple of different NPM components your try that may do the trick.

1. React simple code editor: https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-simple-code-editor
   DEMO: http://satya164.xyz/react-simple-code-editor/
2. React Ace is a bit beefier: https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-ace
   DEMO: https://securingsincity.github.io/react-ace/

happy hacking!